# Get Lowest Point of Scroll on Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible via Javascript to store how far a user has scrolled while on page (pixel-wise), regardless of where they are at any time?

For example, I'd like to track how far someone scrolled before going back up to do a specific action at the top of the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply save the scroll position if it's the lowest one, every time a scroll happens.

```
var maxScroll = 0;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > maxScroll) maxScroll = scroll;
});

// maxScroll is at any time the lowest point of vertical scrolling on the page.
```

You might want to [debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) the handler for better performance.